# Checking Inequalities Expansions using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm using **Sympy** to check that the computations that I'm doing to solve a fully parametric inequality are correct. In this case, I start with `exp1 >= exp2` and I have obtained by hand something of the shape `exp3 >= exp4`. Three of the four expressions are somewhat complex symbolically (as `exp3` is just one variable isolated) and I want to verify that I've made no mistake.

I'd like to either find a way to do this in **Sympy** or if there's any other software/library that's more suited to do this.

Since `exp1-exp2>=0` and `exp3-exp4>=0`, I tried to use `simplify((exp1-exp2)-(exp3-exp4))` and check that the new expression is equal to 0, but that leads to a non-zero value as `(exp1-exp2)=a(exp3-exp4)` with `a` being a non-zero constant value (although symbolic as well). Since I'm isolating one parameter, I've also tried `reduce_inequalities(exp1>=exp2, [I])`, with `I` being the variable isolate in `exp3`, but **Sympy** did not properly isolate the variable and I'm stuck with an intermediate expression.

Comment: This question is too vague to be meaningfully answered. You need to give more detail on what sort of expressions you have ideally just by showing the code to make the expressions with SymPy.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin The problem is not building the expressions, it's finding a general method to verify that the symbolical reduction `exp1>=exp2  =>  exp3>=exp4` is correct (`=>` denotes implication)

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there in terms of checking your answer. You have identified that `e1 - e2` differs by a multiplicative constant from `e3 - e4`. Like an integral's additive constant, the equalities multiplicative constant can be ignored. So if can show, for `d1 >= 0` and `d2 >= 0` (where `di = eq.gts - eq.lts`), that the *ratio* `d1/d2` is constant then you have verified that the two expressions are similar. This will not work, however, if you do things like take roots of one expression and not the other. e.g. `A = x**2 >= 4*y and` B = x > 2*sqrt(y)`.

What about checking to see if the solution for any expression common to both expressions satisfies the other expression, e.g.

```py
from sympy.abc import x, y
from sympy.core.relational import Relational
A = x**2 >= 4*y
B = x > 2*sqrt(y)
a = Relational(A.lhs - A.rhs, 0, A.rel_op)
b = B.lhs - B.rhs
>>> a.subs(x, solve(b,    x,dict=True)[0][x]).expand(),
True
>>> a.subs(y, solve(b    ,y,dict=True)[0][y]).expand(),
True
>>> a.subs(y, solve(b + 1,y,dict=True)[0][y]).expand()
-2*x - 1 >= 0
```